# Strange behaviour when combining dplyr::tbl_df wrapper with gsub function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some code which loops over all columns and cleans a specific string after my defined `gsub()` statement (see below). The strange part is, that the `tbl_df` class from the dplyr package makes the `gsub` behave strangely.

Without first passing my column explicitly `as.data.frame` the `gsub` statement doesn't function properly and will give completely wrong return values (see below). What is causing this behaviour?

I have bypassed this by currently casting my `tbl_df` object into `as.data.frame` before using it within `gsub`.

My code (accessed through debugger, thus the `Browse >` statement

```
Browse[1]> x[,1]
Source: local data frame [70 x 1]

        Symbol
         (chr)
1       AAK.ST
2       ABB.ST
3      ALFA.ST
4  ALIV-SDB.ST
5       AOI.ST
6    ATCO-A.ST
7      AXFO.ST
8      AXIS.ST
9       AZN.ST
10   BALD-B.ST
..         ...
Browse[1]> gsub(pattern = '[-.](.*)$', replacement = '', x = x[,1])
[1] "c(\"AAK" # Wrong behaviour
Browse[1]> gsub(pattern = '[-.](.*)$', replacement = '', x = as.data.frame(x[,1]))
[1] "c(\"AAK" # Still wrong behaviour
Browse[1]> y  <- as.data.frame(x[,1])
Browse[1]> gsub(pattern = '[-.](.*)$', replacement = '', x = y[,1]) # Now it's right(!)
 [1] "AAK"   "ABB"   "ALFA"  "ALIV"  "AOI"   "ATCO"  "AXFO"  "AXIS"  "AZN"   "BALD"  "BETS"  "BILL"  "BOL"   "CAST"  "COMH"  "EKTA"  "ELUX"  "ENQ"   "ERIC"  "FABG"  "GETI"  "HEXA"  "HM"    "HOLM"  "HPOL"  "HUFV" 
[27] "HUSQ"  "ICA"   "IJ"    "INDT"  "INDU"  "INVE"  "JM"    "KINV"  "LATO"  "LIFCO" "LOOM"  "LUMI"  "LUND"  "LUPE"  "MEDA"  "MELK"  "MIC"   "MTG"   "NCC"   "NDA"   "NIBE"  "NOBI"  "ORI"   "PEAB"  "RATO"  "SAAB" 
[53] "SAND"  "SCA"   "SEB"   "SECU"  "SHB"   "SKA"   "SKF"   "SOBI"  "SSAB"  "STE"   "SWED"  "SWMA"  "TEL2"  "TIEN"  "TLSN"  "TREL"  "VOLV"  "WALL"
```

Comment: See the **Methods** section of the help file `?tbl_df`: `[`  *Never simplifies (drops), so always returns data.frame*. `x[, 1]` is not returning a `character` vector,  as `data.frame`s do - `class(x[,1])` will demonstrate that. Using `x$Symbol` instead of `x[,1]` will work.

Comment: Or rather x[[1]] since they're using column indices

Comment: @docendodiscimus could you further explain your statement?

Comment: Also explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526845

Comment: Ok. So using [[ is the same as using $ in R?

Comment: They aren't exactly the same - explained [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#subsetting-operators).

Comment: Not exactly, but when used on a data.frame or tbl_df both always extract a single vector. However you cannot use $ when your column name is stored in a variable (but you can use [[) and [[ allows you to use indices while $ doesn't.